# process is not defined -- GoogleApis library with Remix

Tags: google-api, remix.run

I'm trying to write a Remix app to interact with Google Calendar. I'm using the `googleapis` library which I know is meant for server code. All the code that interacts with the library is running in my `loader` functions, but if I try to return the data from the server to my route component, I get this error in the browser:

```
gaxios.ts:66 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at loadProxy (gaxios.ts:66:9)
    at node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js (gaxios.ts:76:1)
    at __require (chunk-PNG5AS42.js:11:50)
    at node_modules/gaxios/build/src/index.js (index.ts:15:1)
    at __require (chunk-PNG5AS42.js:11:50)
    at node_modules/gcp-metadata/build/src/index.js (index.ts:8:1)
    at __require (chunk-PNG5AS42.js:11:50)
    at node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js (googleauth.js:19:21)
    at __require (chunk-PNG5AS42.js:11:50)
    at node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/index.js (index.js:17:22)
gaxios.ts:66 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at loadProxy (gaxios.ts:66:9)
    at node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js (gaxios.ts:76:1)
    at __require (chunk-PNG5AS42.js:11:50)
    at node_modules/gaxios/build/src/index.js (index.ts:15:1)
    at __require (chunk-PNG5AS42.js:11:50)
    at node_modules/gcp-metadata/build/src/index.js (index.ts:8:1)
    at __require (chunk-PNG5AS42.js:11:50)
    at node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js (googleauth.js:19:21)
    at __require (chunk-PNG5AS42.js:11:50)
    at node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/index.js (index.js:17:22)
```

It makes sense that `process` is not defined in the client, but as I said, all my google-related code is running on the client.

Here is a route. I haven't fully figured out auth yet so when it's not properly logged in, it falls through to the redirect and renders the `other` page which is just a placeholder. When it does log in, it gets the data (`list`) but in the browser the markup renders and the error above shows in the console (no data).

```
export async function loader({}: LoaderArgs) {
  const calendar = google.calendar({
    version: "v3",
  });
  try {
    const list = await calendar.calendarList.list();
    console.log('returning with list');
    return json(list)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }

  console.log('redirecting');
  return redirect('/other')
}

const Index = () => {
  return  <>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <Link to={'/login'}>Login</Link>
  </>;
};

export default Index;
```

When I remove the component, visiting the route returns the JSON no problem.

Any solutions I've seen alluded to use webpack or "vanilla" vite with a `viteConfig`, which I don't think I have access to in remix. Somebody, please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know certain code only being able to run on server/client side, remix has a convention of naming those files `.server.ts` or `.client.ts`. That way none of the code is included in the other build. I would try to extract all the google calendar stuff into a `calendar.server.ts` file and see if the problem persists.

calendar.server.ts:

```
export const getCalendarList = () => {
  const calendar = google.calendar({
    version: "v3",
  });
  return calendar.calendarList.list();
}
```

route:

```
import {getCalendarList} from './calendar.server.ts';

export const loader = async () => {
  const list = await getCalendarList();
}
```

Comment: Oh my god why didn't I think of that you are a LIFE-SAVER! (well, you're at least a project-unblocked)!